# Set execution timeout time when looping through records

Tags: php, timeout, execution

I would like to set a timeout on an execution in php. I want to loop through and I want to cut at 5 for example because of the execution time I set.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',2);
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo time();
    echo ' i:'.$i;
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

would like to give it a limit.

Comment: You can put time() in var before for loop and inside loop chack for the time passed if you want to break loop when 5 seconds expire

Comment: The thing is - that for loop would never take more than 5 seconds.

Comment: http://codepad.org/8iflL06z

Comment: Well than he can't do it in seconds, he has to do count of something and break loop if count exceeds the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ini_set('max_execution_time',2);` would affect the whole PHP script  and may cause

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 2 second exceeded
```

You can simple add your time calculation to your `for` loop instead;

```
$maxTime = 2; // sec ;
$start = time();
echo "<pre>";
for($i = 0; $i < 10, (time() - $start) < $maxTime; $i ++) {
    echo time();
    echo ' i:' . $i;
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    sleep(1); // slow the script
}
```

Output

```
1354287243 i:0

1354287244 i:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a timestamp just before your loop with time(). And put an extra test in the forloop.

```
$startTime = time();
for ($i=0;$i<10 && time() < $startTime + 1000;$i++){
    echo time();
    echo ' i:'.$i;
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```